# filter words from one text file in another text file?

Tags: python

I have a file that is a list of words- one word on each line- filterlist.txt. 
The other file is a giant string of text- text.txt.

I want to find all the instances of the words from filterlist.txt in text.txt and delete them.

Here is what i have so far:

```
text = open('ttext.txt').read().split()
filter_words = open('filterlist.txt').readline()

for line in text:
    for word in filter_words:
        if word == filter_words:
            text.remove(word)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the filter words in a set, iterate over the words from the line  in `ttext.txt`,  and only keep the words that are not in the set of filter words.

```
with open('ttext.txt') as text,  open('filterlist.txt') as filter_words:
    st = set(map(str.rstrip,filter_words))
    txt = next(text).split()
    out = [word  for word in txt if word not in st]
```

If you want to ignore case and remove punctuation you will need to call lower on each line and strip the punctuation:

```
from string import punctuation
with open('ttext.txt') as text,  open('filterlist.txt') as filter_words:
    st = set(word.lower().rstrip(punctuation+"\n") for word in  filter_words)
    txt = next(text).lower().split()
    out = [word  for word in txt if word not in st]
```

If you had multiple lines in `ttext` using `(word for line in text for word in line.split())` would be a more memory efficient approach.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, but I have no idea why because i've never seen this kind of syntax before... I'm totally new to python

Comment: @natalie, it does exactly what your question asks, all the words in that appear in the line from ttext will be removed, out will contain only the words not in filterlist.txt. Add a link to your file contents

Comment: There are `195585` words in the file , the second approach stripping punctuation and lowering returns `82497` words, the first without returns `90853`, how are they not working?

Comment: maybe i'm doing something wrong, am i supposed to print(out) afterwards?

Comment: yes, out will contain all the words not in your filter file. Which approach you take depends on what you want to do, should case match, should foo be considered equal to foo! are you looking for partial matches....

Comment: you're right; it works. I was looking for a specific word which ended up not being in filterwords. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using Padraic Cunningham's principle i coded this in a function

```
from string import punctuation

def vocab_filter(text, filter_vocab):
    txt = text.replace('\n', ' ').lower().split()
    out = [word for word in txt if word not in filter_vocab]
    return out
```

Is very important to use a set, not a list in second argument. Lookups in lists are O(n), lookups in dictionaries are amortized O(1). So for big files this is optimal.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say if this is what you have in the `text.txt` file:`'hello foo apple car water cat'`and this is what you have in the `filterlist.txt` file:`apple car`

```
text = open('text.txt').read().strip("'").split(' ')
    filter_words = open('filterlist.txt').readline().split()
    for i in filter_words:
        if i in text:
            text.remove(i)
            new_text = ' '.join(text)
    print new_text
```

The output will be:

```
hello foo water cat
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my files; I think it's because my filter_words file isn't one long string- the words are all on separate lines. It works if I use your examples, though